# How to calculate sum of values for swift array of NSDictionary

Tags: swift

My dictionary contains a `NSDate` as key and a `Double` as a value. I have an array (swift array) of this dictionaries (`[NSDictionary]`) and I want to calculate the sum of all values of the dictionaries.

I tried to cast it to `Dictionary<NSDate, Double>` (swift way) or to an `NSArray<NSDictionary>` but I always get errors.

Is there a simple way to calculate the sum ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a functional approach:

```
let total = array.reduce(0) { (sum, dict) in sum + (dict.allValues as! [Double]).reduce(0, +) }
```

This uses `reduce` twice.  The inner `reduce` sums up the values for an individual dictionary, and the outer `reduce` sums up the totals from all of the dictionaries.

---

With a reduction in readability, you can use the default argument names `$0` and `$1` to achieve a more compact equation:

```
let total = array.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.allValues as! [Double]).reduce(0, +) }
```

Comment: I am keep getting this error: Could not cast value of type '__NSTaggedDate' (0x10f4660f8) to 'NSNumber' (0x10e64c488).

Comment: That's odd.  Are you sure your NSDictionaries have `NSDate` for key and `Double` for value?  Did you accidentally use `allKeys` instead of `allValues`?

Comment: I managed to make it work, my data would come from Core Data, so the return data was a little different than a simple NSDictionary :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum : Double = 0

for dict in array {
    for (_, value) in dict {
        sum += value as! Double
    }
}

print(sum)
```

I am not exactly sure how your data is set up, but that should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
let sum = array.reduce(0.0) { (result : Double, entry : [Date : Double]) -> Double in
    return result + entry.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.1 }
}
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date0 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-01-16")!
let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-01-17")!
let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-01-18")!

let dict0: NSDictionary = [date0: Double(1), date1: Double(2)]
let dict1: NSDictionary = [date1: Double(3)]
let list: [NSDictionary] = [dict0, dict1]
```

You can calculate the sum of the values writing

```
let sum = list.flatMap { $0.allValues.map { $0 as! Double } }.reduce(0, +) // 6
```

Comment: I am keep getting this error: Could not cast value of type '__NSTaggedDate' (0x10f4660f8) to 'NSNumber' (0x10e64c488).